# Why is the raw JSON object getting returned instead of my partial view?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When I submit my form, the page gets redirected to a new window with the raw json object instead of showing the alerts that I have set up for testing.  I'm guessing that it has something to do with returning a Json result from the controller, but I'm not experienced enough with ajax or json to know why this is happening.

**Partial View (named _FooterButtons)**

```
<div class="row col-12">
    <div class="col-12 footerbuttons">
        <button type="button" onclick="submit()" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-primary" value="Print" style="display: inline-block">Print</button>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Main View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Daily", "Reports", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "reportForm", @class = "report-form col-9" }))
{
...

<partial name="../Shared/_FooterButtons" />
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startdatepicker").datepicker();
    $("#enddatepicker").datepicker();

    // Add the listener only when everything is loaded
    window.onload = function () {
        // Get the form
        let rform = document.getElementById('reportForm');
        console.log(rform);
        // Add the listener
        rform.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            // Avoid normal form process, so no page refresh
            // You'll receive and process JSON here, instead of on a blank page
            e.preventDefault();
            // Include here your AJAX submit:
            console.log("Form submitted");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#reportForm').serialize(),
                url: '@Url.Action("Daily","Reports")',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        alert("Data Success");
                    } else {
                        alert("Data Fail");
                        $('#errorsModal').modal('toggle');
                        $('#errorsModal .modal-body label').html(data.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Daily(Daily dailyReport)
{
    var dr = new ReportDaily();
    var rc = new ReportDailyCriteria();
    dr.Preview(rc, IntPtr.Zero, out Notification notification);
    //dr.CreateReportAsPDF(ReportCriteria(), @"C:/");
    if (notification.HasErrors)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            success = false,
            message = notification.GetConcatenatedErrorMessage(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine)
        });
    }

    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

**Json object that gets returned in a new window**

```
{"success":false,"message":"Must select a payment Source, County and/or Municipal.\r\n\r\nMust select at least one payment type.\r\n\r\nMust select at least one user.\r\n\r\n"}
```

[image: Json Object]

Answer (score 1):

You need to avoid the normal form process and you have 2 options:

First: Add return false to onclick event.

```
<button type="button" onclick="submit(); return false" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-primary" value="Print" style="display: inline-block">Print</button>
```

This first option will be executed only if button is clicked, but maybe not if ENTER key is pressed while typing on an input.

Second and better option: Add an event listener to your form:

```
<script>
// Add the listener only when everything is loaded
window.onload = function() {
    // Get the form
    let rform = document.getElementById('reportForm');
    // Add the listener
    rform.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        // Avoid normal form process, so no page refresh
        // You'll receive and process JSON here, instead of on a blank page
        e.preventDefault();
        // Include here your AJAX submit:
        console.log("Form submitted");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#reportForm').serialize(),
            url: '@Url.Action("Daily","Reports")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    alert("Data Success");
                } else {
                    alert("Data Fail");
                    $('#errorsModal').modal('toggle');
                    $('#errorsModal .modal-body label').html(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
</script>
```

**Edit:** Since you're using jQuery `.ready()`, things are a bit different:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startdatepicker").datepicker();
    $("#enddatepicker").datepicker();

    // Not really sure if window.onload inside .ready() was the problem,
    // but it could be

        // Get the form and add the listener
        $("#reportForm").on('submit', function (e) {
            // Avoid normal form process, so no page refresh
            // You'll receive and process JSON here, instead of on a blank page
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log("Form submitted");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#reportForm').serialize(),
                url: '@Url.Action("Daily","Reports")',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        alert("Data Success");
                    } else {
                        alert("Data Fail");
                        $('#errorsModal').modal('toggle');
                        $('#errorsModal .modal-body label').html(data.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: I've tried both of your suggestions but the form is still being posted in the normal way and still bring up a page with the json.

Comment: Check the console, maybe there's an error that avoids javascript to run as expected.

Comment: no errors in the console before or after the post.  I've tried switching the button to an input with a type of button as well, but that didn't work either.  Do I need to remove `FormMethod.Post` from where the form gets created on the view?

Comment: No, you just need to be sure that form has the ID assigned when you created it: `id = "reportForm"` check HTML source on browser and post here your form tag, so I can edit the answer and make it work

Comment: here is the HTML straight from the developer tools: `<form action="/Reports/Reports/Daily" class="report-form col-9" id="reportForm" method="post">`

Comment: Maybe form is not loaded yet. I've editted my answer enclosing the function inside window.onload.

Comment: I've used your updated code and the behavior is still the same.  I added an alert at the top of the window.onload function just to make sure that it is working properly, and when the page loaded the alert went off correctly. Should I try and add preventDefault to the button?

Comment: Please check the console to see if there's the `Form submitted` message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208444/discussion-between-sjohn285-and-triby).

Comment: There is no "form submitted" message in the console, so the submit event listener is never getting called.

Answer (score 0):

I used a method similar to what Triby has suggested, but instead of adding an event listener on the form submit, I added one onto the submit button click.